# Does AWS ELB handle HA by itself?

Tags: amazon-elb

Maybe a stupid question, but I have searched for a while...

To ensure aws ELB HA, shall I explicitly create two ELB instances in console or aws itself will handle HA for me, so I just need to create one?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it manages HA of itself for you. The main product page mentions this -

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

ELB is engineered to be HA. You can see this by performing a dig command on your ELB and seeing that it returns multiple addresses.

By default an ELB will only send traffic to instances in the region the ELB is in. If you want cross region failover you would need to look here -
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-route-53-elb-integration-dns-failover/

Comment: It seems by default it does not span multi AZ. I'm confused by this line "When you add an Availability Zone to your load balancer, Elastic Load Balancing creates a load balancer node in the Availability Zone." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-disable-az.html
And when you create NLB or ALB you need to specify subnets. If you specify only one subnet, you will have only one ELB node with IPv4 associated, right? In real life when your instances span multi AZ you need to set the same AZs for your ELB which makes it HA.

Answer (score 4):

AWS Elastic Load Balancer(ELB) ensures High Availability(HA) across multiple Availability Zones(AZs) within a Regional Boundary.

Optionally you can select the Availability Zones where the ELB is placed, which impacts HA (Select multiple AZs for Higher Level of HA). You can also configure for multi-region HA using DNS routing policies to send traffic for multiple ELBs in different regions.

> After you enable multiple Availability Zones, if one Availability Zone
>   becomes unavailable or has no healthy instances, the load balancer can
>   continue to route traffic to the healthy registered instances in
>   another Availability Zone.

This is why for DNS mapping, you gets a CName for the ELB(not a A record), since there are multiple servers running behind the ELB for HA and scalability, which is managed by AWS.

For more details check the documentation [How Elastic Load Balancing Works](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html).

Comment: By the answer from BryceH, I see within one AZ, ELB handles HA for me. If I understand correctly, you meant to say, ELB can automatically handles HA for cross-AZ scenario?

Comment: In AWS, it is recommended to design the applications for multiple availability zones for HA to make sure the application works even after a AZ failure.  ELB is having redundancy within the AZ, so it won't fail but risk is high if you don't go with multiple AZ setup.

Comment: thanks, ashan. Shall I create ELB in another AZ or ELB will automatically create/failover to ELB instance in another AZ?