# How to avoid single point of failure in a network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, ip, floating

We have an application (lets call it AppA) that in running in an AWS VPC in a private subnet and there is another application (AppB) which is an on-prem app that talks to AppA via direct connect. AppA is a cluster over multiple AZ’s and we want to put a load balancer in front of it. Putting a load balancer we run into the risk of creating a single point of failure which we want to eliminate. App B is designed only to recognise AppA’s IP address only (no DNS). My question is how we can avoid single point of failure in this situation

Comment: load balancer is highly available by itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021323/does-aws-elb-handle-ha-by-itself

Comment: `App B is designed only to recognise AppA’s IP address only (no DNS)`. What prevents it from using DNS? If you would keep this restriction it would make using load balancer pointles as it's IPs can change at any point of time.

Comment: True. AppB is built only to work with IP address and no DNS. I know .. its a legacy app. we are phasing it out soon.

Answer (score 3):

The load balancer availability is stated to be 99.99% by AWS, which meets the Highly Available requirements.

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

You can see this by performing a dig command on your ELB and seeing that it returns multiple addresses.

By default an ELB will only send traffic to instances in the region the ELB is in. If you want cross region failover you would need to look here - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-route-53-elb-integration-dns-failover/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ELB IP address is dynamic and AppB only works with a non dynamic IP and no DNS. (AppB is a legacy system that we are trying to get rid of but in its own time) :-(

Comment: @vik If you are able to use a network load balancer, they apparently have inherent support for static IPs as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html